# How to distribute table among servers considering load?

Tags: mysql, performance, load

Suppose I have 10 table of different sizes in GB and I have 3 servers and I want to load tables using these servers.

Servers can have different bandwidth. Considering to balance load between servers how I can distribute these tables between servers for loading.

Which algorithm I should use which helps maintain even distribution among all available servers.

Comment: Please add a diagram of what you describe and you can also start with some pseudo-code to allow other to help you. People tend to help out when you already have a starting point, otherwise it will be a theoretical reply and not a practical one.

Comment: It also seems to be more a question for Infrastructure than a DB one.
If you set a load balance in the entry point for the 3 servers and set it to be 50/50, it will distribute requests  according to servers response capacity. However this won't take into account disk usage, so a server that has more requests and stores data will fill up much faster than a slower server.

Comment: Are you "sharding"?  That is, putting parts of a table in each of multiple machines?  Why?